# Call history issue

Tags: call-history

Few of my contacts are receiving a call from my number, which is getting recorded in their call history. But I don't have dialed their number nor does my call log shows the call at times the call goes to people whose number is also not saved.

How is it possible? What could be the issue?

Comment: It seems that you have lost access to your account. To regain access or to merge your multiple accounts, please follow the link [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 0):

You might be having a rogue app with permissions to make calls (android.permission.CALL_PHONE) without user intervention and modify call log (android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG). Unless a competing and more compelling reason  emerges I suggest you single out apps having those permissions and uninstall them until you no longer have this problem.

User Izzy maintains a very good list of [permission checker](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_permissions) apps which you can use to list permissions used by the apps. I use [aSpotCat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.aSpotCat) and I am giving instructions accordingly.

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

In the third image you need to touch those pointed entries to load the apps having the aforementioned permissions.